# search function Laravel 5.2 using LIKE

Tags: php, laravel-5

recently i've been learning lavavel, and i've come to a decent understanding of basic functions within laravel, now i want to be able to search record's from my database and i cant seem to figure out how to do it,

This is the Controller Function i've made for it

```
 public function search()
{
    //searching on producten in the producten database table

    $producten = DB::table('producten')
                ->where('naam', 'LIKE', '%$query%')
                ->get();
}
```

and this is what My View looks like

```
 {!! Form::open(['route' => 'producten.index', 'method' => 'GET', 'class' => 'search']) !!}

        {!! Form::text('naam')!!}

     {!! Form::close() !!}
```

if i go on the view in my browser, and type a Product name into the text box, the url changes to producten?naam=ProductNaam but nothing different is showen on the screen, i hope this is enough information to help me, just let me know if i need to add anything to the question.

Comment: Did you try with `method="POST"`

Comment: Where are you defining `$query` in your function?

Comment: $query has to be a valid value, there's is not defined or retrieved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your view is correct , but your controller doesn't accept anything.

You are currently searching for the products where the name has 'query' inside it.

So you have to accept the Request inside your search method.

Like so:

```
public function search(Request $request)
```

`$request->naam` will give you the value you typed inside your text field. Obviously you still need to validate that value.

I would also recommend filtering on the Model, your code will be more readable.

```
 Product::where('naam', 'LIKE', "%$request->naam%")->get();
```

You should read this page , this will give you a better understanding of your problem
https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests

Comment: with your comment do u mean that  i have to add Request $request and  change my query to this:  DataBaseTable::where('naam', 'LIKE', "%$request->naam%")->get(); ?

Comment: the important part is adding  Request $request and $request->naam, the last line is just an alternative for DB::table('producten'). That will only work if you have a Model called Product.

Comment: in the view the ['route' => 'producten.index'] refers to the controller function it uses right?

Comment: yes, so that should point to your search method not your index method. I would recommend watching this series: https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-from-scratch . its free, it will help you greatly.

Answer (score 0):

Just fix the quotes here: `->where('naam', 'LIKE', "%$query%")`

- Single quotes: Its content is treated as string literal
- Double quotes: Allows special characters like $, \n, \t...

More info [can be found in the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Answer (score 0):

Your controller function should be as:

```
public function search()
{
    //searching on producten in the producten database table

    $query = request()->get('naam');

    $producten = DB::table('producten')
                ->where('naam', 'LIKE', "%$query%")
                ->get();

    // pass the `$producten` result to your search view.
}
```